# perl - populate several variables from regex group within while

Tags: regex, perl

I'm learning perl, and now i'm trying to populate several variables at the same time, from the match captures, in a while group. I have the "long" version working, as bellow:

```
$pc = ...
while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
    $var1 = $1; 
    $var2 = $2;
    $var3 = $3;
    $var4 = $4;
    $var5 = $5;
    $var6 = $6;
    ...
}
```

for a single capture (outside a while loop) I know I can do this:

```
my $string = 'abcde';
my @captures = $string =~ m/.(.)(.)(.)./;
my ($aa,$ab,$ac) = @captures;
print ("$aa - $ab - $ac\n");
```

Is there a way to populate all the vars within the while loop at once? do I need to do something like the code bellow, or is there an easier (that does not require 2 regular expressions) way?

```
while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla7/g) {
    my @captures = $1 =~ m/(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)/;
    ($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6) = @captures;
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `my ($aa,$ab,$ac) = $string =~ m/.(.)(.)(.)./;` would work just as well for your "oustside a while loop" code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could use

```
while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
    my ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
    ... $var3 ...
}
```

or

```
while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
    my @vars = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
    ... $vars[2] ...
}
```

or

```
sub captures { map substr($_[0], $-[$_], $+[$_] - $-[$_]), 1..$#- }

while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
    my @vars = captures($pc);
    ... $vars[2] ...
}
```

or

```
sub captures { no strict 'refs'; map $$_, 1..$#- }

while ($pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
    my @vars = captures();
    ... $vars[2] ...
}
```

or

```
while ($pc =~ m/bla1(?<var1>.*?)bla2(?<var2>.*?)bla3(?<var3>.*?)bla4(?<var4>.*?)bla5(?<var5>.*?)bla6(?<var6>.*?)bla7/g) {
    ... $+{vars3} ...
}
```

Comment: Note that any of the `my @vars =` can be replaced with `my ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6) =`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$pc = ...
while ( my @captured = $pc =~ m/bla1(.*?)bla2(.*?)bla3(.*?)bla4(.*?)bla5(.*?)bla6(.*?)bla7/g) {
```